# How to open the app link on the facebook wall in a new window?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have an app which is posting the news on my wall. if i click the news link its is opening the redirection link on the same page rather than opening it on the new tab(like it does in the washington post). I figured it out as they have added target="_blank" in their  tag. But i don't know how to add target="_blank" in the FB.api which holds the redirect link.

Comment: Can you post a link showing this behavior?  Every link i click in facebook that is a reference to an external site will open in a new window.

Comment: Your link may be pointing back to your facebook page, which should open in the same window of your browser.  However, if your link goes to an external site, it may popout in a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Script Language="JavaScript">
function load() {
var load =window.open('http://_your_facebook_link','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
}
// -->
</Script>
```

Refer [this](http://www.web-source.net/javascript_popup_window2.htm) link

Hope this may help you